# How do I change colors of multiple lines in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

> I am trying to plot a simple graph that has 2 sets of x data (ie, two lines). I want to change the default colors of these two lines. I have included the code for my graph below, can someone help explain where I should insert code to specify the colors for the type1 and type2 of my data?

```
ggplot(data = nihss, aes(x=pmri, y=nihss, group=type, color=type)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(fill=type)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +  
  labs(y="NIHSS at Time of Exam", x="pMRI Hematoma Volume (cc)")+ 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", color="black")) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=14)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black"))
```

Comment: You could add `+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`.

Comment: Thanks! That helped turn the lines a different color, how do I change the geom_smooth(aes(fill=type)) (ie, the error area) to change color as well?

Comment: Typically by doing `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`, but alternatively you can use `+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))`.

Comment: That's super helpful! Thanks so much. Worked perfectly!